# Fetching Views 3 implementation from code

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 7. What I want to do is to fetch the View 3 implementation from code, rather than from database, so that I can export my view, and put it in a function that would be available to all my team members w/o the need of importing the database script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [hook_views_default_views()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_default_views/7).

Remember to implement [hook_views_api()](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_views_api/7) in mymodule.module file, so that views can find your views stored in code using `hook_views_default_views()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite some different ways to achieve this

- Use the ctools bulk export module, this will provide you some example code to use
- use the features module, which gives you a full module